# UILocalNotification design paradigm

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a few questions regarding UILocalNotifications and how I can design my app.

1. I have an application that monitors an FX (foreign exchange) data feed. What I want to do is add a feature where the user can set an alert to occur when the price hits a certain value.
   There are then two scenarios - When the app is running and when it's not.
   If the app is running then I can monitor the feed in the app and schedule and display a notification if the price is reached. (this I understand)
   If it's not running then am I correct in my asumption that in order to monitor the feed my only option is to use the background task completion in iOS 6?
   If so I guess this isn't going to work as I only get 15 minutes on background time, so after that there would be no way to monitor the feed and thus display a notification.
   so.... A) is this a correct asumption? B) Is my only way to get longer than 15 minutes background time to use Push Notifications and monitor the feed on a server? C) How will iOS7 change this can I run arbitrary code in the background?
2. I have read the documenation but I cannot figure out how to present a UILocalnotifcation with a UIAlertView style look, rather than the drop down thing at the top of the screen?
3. If I schedule more than 64 notifications I understand the OS cancels any after that... Our of interest what if an app (malicious or not) setup 64 local notications (potentially repeating) how could a user cancel these if the app is badly coded and doesn't cancel them itself?? Would a restart destroy any scheduled notifications?
4. If I want to present a notificaiton when the app is running, do I bascailly catch the notficaiton in a delegate method and arrange to display the message myself?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: Sure, if you wish to close this and I will open 4 separate questions no problem?

Comment: Yes, but they also need to be more detailed. For item 2, for instance, explain your research and exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: I think for number two he's referring to changing the style of the notification from `Banner` (white bar across the top of the screen that disappears) and `Alert` (just a `UIAlertView`)

Comment: @RazorSharp that's correct any ideas!?

Comment: I was waiting until the question was "split" to answer, but I guess I'll give it a shot here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are my ansers:

1A, Yes, the assumption is correct, your app can't run indefinitely in background

1B, Using PushNotifications won't give you longer time to execute in background, but your app can be notified at any time so this can be a a solution, but you can't rely on the notifications order so be careful.

1C I didn't check the latest features of iOS 7 but I doubt that they will provide indefinitely background running (like Android services)

2.Set the `alertBody` `If the value of this property is non-nil, an alert is displayed` but I don't think you can *force* the style of the alert, but if a user has set the style of the alerts then he will expect to receive them with that style so I think you shouldn't bother with this issue to much.

3.Not sure of this one, it's kind of tricky but you can test it ;)

4.YES, use `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

Comment: @JohnWoods I typed a huge answer, only to scroll up and find out that when I finished typing the question was *on hold* and I can no longer submit it. :(

Comment: Aww man sorry, I didn't put on hold! the community did, thanks for all the help anyway! any chance you can paste it into a comment??